# How to add corresponding date to grouped max/min-value in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I have a climate timeseries table with different measured parameters for many stations over some years (daily values). I am using postgres 9.4 with pgadmin.

The table looks this way:

Table name **kl**

```
station_id [int], 
date [date], 
temperature [numeric] ...
```

my select Code:

```
select 
  stat_id,
  max(temperatur) as "T_max"
from kl 
group by stat_id
order by stat_id
```

gives out the max-temperature value for every station:[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfpYT.png)

Now the question: how to add for every T_max value the corresponding date in another column (the date on which that max value was measured)?

thanks for your help

Comment: If possible then can you write your desired result, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You use **[row_number()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html)** to get the whole row

`PARTITION BY` reset the row counter for each station, so you wont need `group by`.

```
WITH cte as ( 
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id 
                               ORDER BY temperature DESC) AS rn
     FROM kl 
) 
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

And just change `*` for the field names you need

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (stat_id)
    stat_id, temperatur, date
from kl 
order by stat_id, temperatur desc
```

Use the `date` column (bad name) to untie:

```
order by stat_id, temperatur desc, date
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

If you want both the min and max temperatures in the same query:

```
with kl (stat_id, temperatur, date) as (values
    (1, 17.1, '2015-01-01'::date), (1, 17.2, '2015-01-02')
)
select stat_id,
    t_max[1]::numeric as t_max,
    (date 'epoch' + t_max[2] * interval '1 second')::date as d_max,
    t_min[1]::numeric as t_min,
    (date 'epoch' + t_min[2] * interval '1 second')::date as d_min
from (
    select
        stat_id,
        max(array[temperatur, extract(epoch from date)::numeric]) as t_max,
        min(array[temperatur, extract(epoch from date)::numeric]) as t_min
    from kl
    group by 1
) s
;
 stat_id | t_max |   d_max    | t_min |   d_min    
---------+-------+------------+-------+------------
       1 |  17.2 | 2015-01-02 |  17.1 | 2015-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.  Both ways work well for the described problem.